# How to define placeholders in Ui-Binder?

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

I want to create an EditPanel, which basically is always the same, only some `TextBox` fields differs.

Thus I thought I'd create a `Widget`, define the layout etc with ui-binder and make it have some kind of placeholder where a widget can be placed in. But how would I do this?

```
<g:FlowPanel>
<g:Label text="This is an edit panel" />

<<place here my dynamic widget that I want to pass into that class>>

<g:Button text="save" />
<g:Button text="cancel" />
<g:Button text="reset" />
<g:Label text="some more fixed text" />
</g:FlowPanel>
```

You get the idea what I'm trying to do.
But how can I eg create another `FlowPanel` with some `TextBox` fields and place it into the `EditPanel`??

Comment: little confused the above code is editpanel?

Comment: Yes it's supposed to be the edit panel which provides basic stylings, panel handling, buttons etc. Only the text boxes should then be placed into that editpanel from outside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define one `empty` `panel` there like

```
<g:HorizontalPanel ui:field="dynamicContentPanel"> </g:HorizontalPanel>
```

define that in `view` .

```
@UiField
HorizontalPanel  dynamicContentPanel;
```

Use like  `dynamicContentPanel`.add(`yourDynamicWidget`);